# Java - Array value, memory address or?

Tags: java, arrays

This code

```
public static void main(String [] args){
     int c[] ={10,21,34,36,90,33,44,5};
     int tot = 0;
  for(int i:c){
      System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

Prints out

```
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
 [I@1242719c
```

I know I'm supposed to print out the int variable, but I'm curious as to what this means. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you use `System.out.println(i);` (print i, not c)?

Comment: I know that. I'm asking why "c" gives that output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're printing out the internal representation of `c`. Essentially `[I@1242719c` breaks down to two important things. First, the `[` indicates that you're printing an array. Second, the `I` indicates that it's an integer. Therefore, you're printing an array of integers! Try replacing the integer array with a string array and watch the `I` get replaced accordingly. [From this page](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm6.html):

> The name of an array's class has one open square bracket for each
>   dimension plus a letter or string representing the array's type. For
>   example, the class name for an array of ints is "[I". The class name
>   for a three-dimensional array of bytes is "[[[B". The class name for a
>   two-dimensional array of Objects is "[[Ljava.lang.Object". The full
>   details of this naming convention for array classes is given in
>   Chapter 6, "The Java Class File."

Comment: More information in the "Type Signatures" section of the [JNI spec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html).